# AS3/Flash: check if a variable value exists in an array II

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Some days ago, Cherniv gave to me this tip:

```
var name = "Nora";
var names:Array = ["Mary", "Porter", "Nora", "Flint", "Elsa", "Clair",...];

if( names.indexOf( name ) > -1 )
{
// Success
}
```

Now, I can't check the existence of "Nora" in this array:

```
var names:Array = [{label:"Mary"}, {label:"Porter"},{label:"Nora"}, ...];
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

Now it's working. I did use:

```
for each (var obj:Object in list)
{
    if (obj.label == compList.text)
    {
        updateList = 1;
        break;//stops the loop;
    }
}
if (updateList == 1)
{
    removeCompany();
}
else
{
    var nativeAlert:NativeAlert = new NativeAlert();
    nativeAlert.alert("You can't update the name!");
}
```

Is this OK or is an ugly solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for each( var obj : Object in names )
{
    if( obj.label == "Nora" )
    {
    // Success;
       break;//stops the loop;
    }
}
```

I can make it more complex/flexible if you wish.

Comment: may I add a call to a function just before the break?

Comment: yes! you can remove the break so each time it finds "Nora" it calls that function. Your example was made for only the first time it finds "Nora".

Comment: @Sergio If the answer satisfies your question, please accept the answer. thank you!

Comment: I did need just to find the first one only and delete it from the array. I did get it working but I'd like to know if the piece of code is OK or there are a better way. Please, see the UPDATE. Many thanks.

Comment: its fine, add a var updateList : Number = 0; before the loop.